# Remove key when filter collections laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I ran into a problem when using filter with Laravel 5.2, after filtering, I got some unexpected key like "0", "1", "2" ..., how can I remove it?

Before filter:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 11,
    "location": "1",
    "content": "1",
    "interest_id": 1,
    "longitude": 1,
    "latitude": 1,
    "place_id": "1",
    "created_at": "2016-06-09 15:44:18",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-02 14:28:42",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 12,
    "location": "Forest Lake QLD, Australia",
    "content": "I'm newbie. Hello everybody",
    "interest_id": 1,
    "longitude": 152.9692508,
    "latitude": -27.6236519,
    "place_id": "ChIJB_NHl8hOkWsRMIne81qjAgU",
    "created_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "user_id": 11,
    "location": "Hendra QLD, Australia",
    "content": "What time is it?",
    "interest_id": 1,
    "longitude": 153.0635202,
    "latitude": -27.4225981,
    "place_id": "ChIJAXNg5PBYkWsRIIve81qjAgU",
    "created_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "user_id": 11,
    "location": "Hendra QLD, Australia",
    "content": "Nice Cream!!!!????????",
    "interest_id": 2,
    "longitude": 153.0635202,
    "latitude": -27.4225981,
    "place_id": "ChIJAXNg5PBYkWsRIIve81qjAgU",
    "created_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 17,
    "location": "Forest Lake QLD, Úc",
    "content": "Have a nice day!",
    "interest_id": 1,
    "longitude": 152.9692508,
    "latitude": -27.6236519,
    "place_id": "ChIJB_NHl8hOkWsRMIne81qjAgU",
    "created_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "user_id": 18,
    "location": "Hendra QLD, Australia",
    "content": "Where is Kiet Bui? ❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️",
    "interest_id": 1,
    "longitude": 153.0635202,
    "latitude": -27.4225981,
    "place_id": "ChIJAXNg5PBYkWsRIIve81qjAgU",
    "created_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "deleted_at": null
  }
]
```

After filter, id > 5 for example:

```
{
  "2": {
    "id": 8,
    "user_id": 11,
    "location": "Hendra QLD, Australia",
    "content": "What time is it?",
    "interest_id": 1,
    "longitude": 153.0635202,
    "latitude": -27.4225981,
    "place_id": "ChIJAXNg5PBYkWsRIIve81qjAgU",
    "created_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 9,
    "user_id": 11,
    "location": "Hendra QLD, Australia",
    "content": "Nice Cream!!!!????????",
    "interest_id": 2,
    "longitude": 153.0635202,
    "latitude": -27.4225981,
    "place_id": "ChIJAXNg5PBYkWsRIIve81qjAgU",
    "created_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  "5": {
    "id": 7,
    "user_id": 18,
    "location": "Hendra QLD, Australia",
    "content": "Where is Kiet Bui? ❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️",
    "interest_id": 1,
    "longitude": 153.0635202,
    "latitude": -27.4225981,
    "place_id": "ChIJAXNg5PBYkWsRIIve81qjAgU",
    "created_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-09 14:28:42",
    "deleted_at": null
  }
}
```

How can I remove the key 2, 3, and 5 in the result and only get an array like before filtering. Any help is appreciate.
Edit:
My code:

```
 $result = $result->filter(function ($item) {
                return $item->id > 5;
            })->all();
```

Comment: give me your code plz, what did you trying?

Comment: why don't try `->reject(function ($row) {return $row->id<5;});`

Comment: @SafoorSafdar: I've tried it, but it return same result :(

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try adding `values()`

```
$result = $result->filter(function ($item) {
                return $item->id > 5;
            })->values()->all();
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped me too.

Comment: I got something slightly different.  Rather than $collection->values()->all()  I just used $colleciton->values().  all() returned an array but values returned a keyless colleciton

Comment: I use flatten(), it also removed the keys

Comment: i think no need to use `all()` regarding documentation, read detail here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-values

Answer (score 5):

I had have the same problem when sorting:
The example is ordering games result by points and goals. The sorting add key attr in the result. So I use in the final ->values()->all() to get an array values without keys.

Eg:

```
$sorted = $resultados->sortByDesc('pts')->sortByDesc('gf')->values()->all();
```

In your case:

```
$filteredValues = $filtered->values()->all();
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that if you want to use `filter()` helper, because that's just how this helper works. I mean there are no parameters or something for this method. You can only rebuild returned collection.

Or, you can use `filter()` method code to create your own helper, like `myFilter()` and modify it a bit, for example:

```
public function myFilter(callable $callback)
{
    $return = [];

    foreach ($this->items as $key => $value) {
        if ($callback($value, $key)) {
            // $return[$key] = $value; // original line from filter() method
            $return[] = $value; // Here you want to remove $key
        }
    }

    return new static($return);
}
```

Or you could just use collection with indices. I mean usually you're using collection to iterate over it and these indices won't disturb you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $result->filter(function ($item) {
                return $item->id < 5;
            })->all();
```

Enjoy !!

```
        $collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);

        $filtered = $collection->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item < 2;
        });

        $filtered->all();
        return $filtered;
```

result:
[
  1
]

But:

```
    $collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);

    $filtered = $collection->filter(function ($item) {
        return $item > 2;
    });

    $filtered->all();
    return $filtered;
```

Result: {
  "2": 3,
  "3": 4
}

don't know how, why...